# Как програмно включить фонарик?

Tags: java, android

Добрый день. Мне надо добавить «фонарик» в своё приложение, пробовал добавить его, он не хочет работать. Как ни крути показывает мне мой же алерт «У вашего телефона отсутствует фонарик» хотя и камера и фонарик присутствуют. Никакой толковой информации в интернете по нему не нашел. Как же всё-таки включить и выключить фонарик?

Код:

```
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class MainActivity extens Activity {

Camera camera = null;
ToggleButton toggleTorch;
Parameters parameters;
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
AlertDialog alertDialog;
private final int FLASH_NOT_SUPPORTED = 0;
private final int FLASH_TORCH_NOT_SUPPORTED = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    toggleTorch = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);

    // если камера имеет вспышку
    if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
            PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)) {

        toggleTorch
            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                             boolean isChecked) {
                    // включаем фонарик
                    if (isChecked) {
                        if (camera == null) {
                            camera = Camera.open();
                            parameters = camera.getParameters();
                            List flashModes = parameters
                                .getSupportedFlashModes();
                            if (flashModes
                                .contains(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH)) {
                                parameters
                                    .setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                                camera.setParameters(parameters);
                                camera.startPreview();
                            } else {
                                showDialog(MainActivity.this,
                                           FLASH_TORCH_NOT_SUPPORTED);
                            }

                        }
                    } else { // выключаем фонарик
                        parameters
                            .setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                        camera.setParameters(parameters);
                        camera.stopPreview();
                        camera.release();
                        camera = null;
                    }
                }
            });
    } else {
        showDialog(MainActivity.this, FLASH_NOT_SUPPORTED);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (camera != null) {
        camera.release();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (camera != null) {
        camera.release();
    }
}

public void showDialog(Context context, int dialogId) {
    switch (dialogId) {
        case FLASH_NOT_SUPPORTED:
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setMessage("Ваше устройство не поддерживает вспышку")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setNeutralButton("Close", new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }
                });
            alertDialog = builder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
            break;
        case FLASH_TORCH_NOT_SUPPORTED:
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setMessage("Ваше устройство не поддерживает вспышку")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setNeutralButton("Close", new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }
                });
            alertDialog = builder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Разметка:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="20dip"
    android:text="Фонарик"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dip"
    android:textOff="Вкл."
    android:textOn="Выкл." />
```

Comment: Приложите свой код.

Comment: пермишн не забыли добавить?

Comment: Всё, добавил код

Comment: @Михаил ,  приведите пожалуйста layout, чтобы можно было код быстро воспроизвести

Comment: @Михаил Ребров, добавил.

Comment: @Михаил, класс активити ещё целиком приложите (вместе с импортами)

Comment: @МихаилРебров, добавил

Comment: Попробуйте вынести `builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);` перед `switch` строкой, во втором кейсе удалите

Answer (score 1):

Cкорее всего Вы забыли указать permission в androidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
```

Comment: Нет, всё добавлял

Comment: @Михаил, все три? (я добавил ещё один - android.permission.FLASHLIGHT)

Comment: да, но не работает всё равно

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте в конце блока

`if (isChecked) {`

поменять/присвоить

```
buttonView.isChecked = false;
```

и в этом блоке, в конце

`} else {`

```
buttonView.isChecked = true;
```

У вас `isChecked` видимо постоянно держит одно значение.

[Пример вашей задачи](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/04/android-developing-flashlight-application/)

___________ Обсуждение

1 - Почему у вас эти наборы строк

```
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setMessage("Ваше устройство не поддерживает вспышку")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setNeutralButton("Close", new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
        alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
```

идентичные в разных `case`?

2 - Вынесите `builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);` перед `switch` строкой, во втором кейсе удалите эту строку

3 - во втором `case` отсутствует `break`

Comment: @Михаил как конкретно вы меняли isChecked?

Comment: @Михаил расставьте логи и проследите где какое значение на что указывает.

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас версия android>21 то вы должны использовать camera2

Пример кода:

```
CameraManager camManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        String cameraId = null; // Usually back camera is at 0 position.
        try {
            cameraId = camManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
            camManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true);   //Turn ON
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Нет, мне надо на 4.0.3+

Comment: На тестируемом устройстве какая версия?

Comment: @РасулА-ев, 4.2.2