# Включение вспышки на определенное время на Андроид

Tags: android

Пишу приложение, которое взаимодействует вспышку телефона.
Подскажите, какой нужно использовать код, чтобы запустить вспышку камеры (не включая саму камеру) на определенное время в миллисекундах?

Comment: да, поправил заголовок

Comment: Простите, некорректно написал. Конечно же требуется код для написания программы, которая бы включала вспышку на определенное время

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот в этом вопросе, на этом ресурсе, содержится полный ответ на ваш вопрос: 
[как добавить фонарик в моё приложение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/677850/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA)

Comment: спасибо, это почти то. нужно, чтобы вспышка автоматически выключалась спустя определенное время (которое я мог бы задать программно)

Comment: 'TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);'  используйте подобный таймер