# Не работает фонарик на Android 8.0

Tags: java, android

Использую в приложении фонарик таким образом:

```
    mSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
           
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        
        if (camera == null) {
            camera = Camera.open();
        }
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        if (!isChecked) {
            parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        } else {
            parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        }
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera.startPreview();
        
      }
   });
```

В манифесте указано данное разрешение:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Использую среду разработки Eclipse. Также в Properties проекта использую Project Build Target: Android 4.2.2.

До этого работоспособность фонарика тестировалась на Android 4.4, все работало исправно. Сейчас же на Android 8.0 при включении ничего не происходит. Как можно это исправить?

Comment: Уже примерно 100500 лет надо не просто указывать разрешение в манифесте, но и запрашивать его у пользователя.

Comment: @Эникейщик С указанным в вопросе Project Build Target: Android 4.2.2 при установке приложения на Android 6.0 и выше система активирует это разрешение по умолчанию.

Comment: Посмотрите этот ответ:https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/677865/367395